# How to draw self-call and recursive call with Umbrello?

Tags: uml, umbrello

How can you draw a self-call and recursive call with Umbrello like this

[image]

The only option I can see from the app calls to other actors.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is not the answer you expected, but I installed it to try and that tool is just unusable, good luck .... or better move to an other tool.